# Huggingface - TypeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object is not subscriptable

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, transformer, huggingface

I'm trying to make my own model for translate a language to another with [T5ForConditionalGeneration](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/t5.html#t5forconditionalgeneration) and Huggingface using no pretrained model (I need to use my own dataset and tokenizer because no pretrained model exists for the languages I use). When running the train() method, I get the following error: TypeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object is not subscriptable

I suppose it is due to the type of the dataset given to the Trainer (TensorSliceDataset), but I can't figure out what should be the structure and type of the dataset that I should use for language translation. Can someone give me an example of dataset structure? I do not understand how the model can find the x and y labels if we don't tell it explicitly which column should be x and y.
[Source code of the example.](https://gist.github.com/TristanBilot/4cca4733faaa171f0475cb6cff4c634a)

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No I couldn't find out the solution